# Outputting a 3D array as a table

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

Im making a blackjack game for an assignment and have arrays for leaderboard and cards.

I want to print the leader board like this. CARDS(in individual cells)| TOTAL.

help would be appreciated, thanks

```
function makeTable(leaderBoard) {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    for (var i = 0; i < leaderBoard.length; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        for (var j = 0; j < leaderBoard[i].length; j++) {
            var cell = document.createElement('td');
            cell.textContent = leaderBoard[i][j];
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
    document.getElementById('leaderBoard').innerHTML = table;
}
```

Comment: what have you done already ???

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeTable(leaderBoard) {
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < leaderBoard[0].length; i++) {
        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.textContent = leaderBoard[0][i];
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.textContent = "Total: " + leaderBoard[1];
    row.appendChild(cell);
    table.appendChild(row);
    document.getElementById('leaderBoard').appendChild(table);
}

var userCards = ["Card 1", "Card 2", "Card 3"];
var userTotal = 10;
makeTable([userCards, userTotal]);
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/25kg3nnq/**

Comment: this is the result - [object HTMLTableElement]

Comment: this is the array leaderBoard = [[usercards][usertotal]]

Comment: Can you give an example entry and the output you want?

Comment: the cards are collected when the player wins in an array like this ["card1","card2"]. i then make a variable called info that includes the cards array and the total as an int like this var info = [userCards,usersTotal]. then i do leaderBoard.push(info) and i want the table to output all this info in different cells

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the example input isn't in the correct format, but reusing a predefined table and html table functions such as insertRow and insertCell (not necessarily better, but they can be easier on the eye than createElement and append) :

```
<div id="leaderBoard"><table id=leaderTable></table></div>

function updateleaderboard(leaderBoard) {    
    var table = document.getElementById('leaderTable');
    while(table.rows.length > 0) table.deleteRow(0); //remove prev values, if any    
    for (var i = 0; i < leaderBoard.length; i++) { //If the function is always used on a winner (no ties), the loop isn't really needed
        var row =table.insertRow();
        var arrCards = leaderBoard[i++];
        var total = row.insertCell();
        total.className = 'res';
        total.textContent = leaderBoard[i];
        arrCards.forEach(function(c,ind){
            row.insertCell(ind).textContent = c;
        });
    }
}

var cards = [['Q','4','5'],19];

updateleaderboard(cards);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8134fr5u/1/)